# Why can't I define a nested class externally?

Tags: c++, mingw, external, definition, nested-class

I'm having trouble putting together an object model that involves nested classes, using MinGW C++. Here is an example that exposes my issue:

foo.h:

```
/*
 * foo.h
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 25, 2011
 *      Author: AutoBot
 */

#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_

class Foo
{
public:
    class Bar;
    Bar bar;
} extern foo;


#endif /* FOO_H_ */
```

bar.h:

```
/*
 * bar.h
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 25, 2011
 *      Author: AutoBot
 */

#ifndef BAR_H_
#define BAR_H_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "foo.h"

class Foo::Bar
{
public:
    void Test() {cout <<"Test!";}
};


#endif /* BAR_H_ */
```

main.cpp:

```
/*
 * main.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 25, 2011
 *      Author: AutoBot
 */



#include "foo.h"

Foo foo;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    foo.bar.Test();
    return 0;
}
```

Eclipse CDT build log:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project NestedClassTest ****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src\main.o ..\src\main.cpp
In file included from ..\src\main.cpp:10:0:
..\src\/foo.h:15:6: error: field 'bar' has incomplete type
..\src\main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
..\src\main.cpp:16:6: error: 'class Foo' has no member named 'bar'
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 171  ms.
```

So essentially it's failing to recognize the definition of bar I made in bar.h. Is this normal? Why shouldn't I be able to define nested classes this way? Is this simply a limitation of the MinGW toolchain? Any help/advice is appreciated.

Side note: in my actual program, I intend for the "foo" of it to serve as, theoretically, a singleton class. It would represent the application as a whole, and it's subsystems (or "bars") would be defined and instantiated once inside the class. I'm doing this to try to make the code more manageable. If anyone has a more feasible design pattern in mind, please tell me!

Comment: Why do you need an object that represents the application? The application is represented by the fact that it is _running_. If code can execute, then you're in the application. I could understand using a singleton to provide access to certain specific data (a filesystem, for example), but having a singleton to represent the application doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps I'm putting too much into one class. One thing I want the singleton to manage for sure is the startup/shutdown and servicing of all the subsystems (via `start`, `end`, and `update` functions). This gave me the tendency to put all of the actual subsystems inside of it as well, but I probably shouldn't do that as that limits code use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    class Bar;
    Bar bar;
};
```

At this point `Foo::Bar` is an incomplete type. And you cannot declare a variable of an incomplete type. It would be no different from trying to do this:

```
class Foo;
Foo foo;
```

They're both not allowed and for the same reason.

You could turn `bar` into some kind of (smart) pointer. But that's the only way to solve this.

Comment: "there is no point to making it a nested class"... Sure there is, all members of `Foo::Bar` can access private members of `Foo`.

Comment: What Ben Voigt said, in fact this is a key reason why I'm trying to sustain this model. Basically I want all of my subsystems to be able to interact with each other while residing inside the singleton class (read my side note in op). Maybe I could just find a way to use friend classes and build it up from there.

Comment: Actually, friend classes wouldn't cut it as I'd still have to specify foo's members as `foo.bar1`, `foo.bar2`, etc... (instead of just `bar1` and `bar2`). I've used Nicol Bolas's pointer idea and after some tweaking it seems to work. I'll continue to pursue this object model if the pointers won't give me too much trouble. I do understand that at the time bar was evaluated, it was incomplete, but I suppose it's unfortunate that I must resort to pointers because of that. Either way it works now. Thanks!

Comment: @BenVoigt Oops, I forgot about that. Edited.

Comment: @AutoBotAM Classes should not be able to willy-nilly access each other's privates. Even classes within the same subsystem. That defeats the whole purpose of encapsulation: the reasonable assurance that the number of functions that can affect a piece of state is limited. What you're doing cannot do that.

Comment: I still intend for the subsystems to be encapsulated, and they would be in this case. The only private members being accessed are those of Foo's, and that is only to allow interaction between subsystems. I'm actually not even sure if private access to even Foo would be necessary. I'm starting to second guess the idea of having some large omnipotent class though, it makes the code a bit more complicated after a while.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems you have here, is that when you do:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    class Bar;
    Bar bar;
} extern foo;
```

`Bar bar` is illegal because you are trying to use the `class bar;` which provides an incomplete type.

You also do not include Bar.h

Comment: If I change `Bar bar` to `Bar *bar` (foo.h), add `#include "foo.h"` (bar.h), and change `foo.bar.Test()` to `foo.bar->Test()` (main.cpp), I get two errors: `..\src\/bar.h:16:7: error: 'Foo' has not been declared` and `..\src\/bar.h:17:1: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token` So it looks like the bar has been initialized correctly, but now Bar cannot see Foo! xD

Comment: That would only work if you also included bar.h in main.cpp and removed the include foo.h from bar.h .

Comment: Alright, I've done that and it seems to work now! I'll keep pursuing this object model if the pointers won't cause too much trouble. Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend you to use some std::shared_ptr or boost::shared_ptr for the Bar instance. This would throw away the need to handle yourself the pointer, as soon as it's no more used by your class it will be released.